# custom attribute for string property

Tags: c#, .net, string, filter, custom-attributes

i have a question.
I would like to do something like that:

```
[PutStars]
public string telephone
```

where `PutStars` could be a custom attribute for example.

PutStars acts on the string, so it replace telephone value `[333-123456789]` and when getting value, it retrieves for example `[333-12xxxx789]`.

Is it possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What type of project do you have? Web, WPF, ...?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can't do something like that with attributes. You need a helper method which does the job for you.

Comment: i have a Web project

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can implement a helper method and call it when getting the value:

```
private string _tel;
public string Tel 
{
  set{ _tel = value; }
  get {
    return _tel.PutStars();
  }
}

public static string PutStars(this string str)
{
 return str.Replace("1", "*");
}
```

Alternatively when you get the string you can do:

```
var starred = myObj.Tel.PutStars();
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest you'll get to that *inbuilt* will probably be `[PasswordPropertyText]`, but a: that is intended to mask an entire field, and b: it depends entirely on the UI framework you are using looking for this attribute; nothing is automatic in attributes. Your best bet, frankly, is probably to add a second property that you use for UI binding:

```
public string Telephone {get;set;}

public string TelephoneMasked {
    get { /* your code here */ }
}
```

and bind to `TelephoneMasked`.

Comment: I have not ui binding. I need the value for other purposes.. !